# Passing data to instantiated view controller without segue

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox

I'm trying to pass a simple value forward to an instantiated view controller. I'm not sure of the right way to do it.

I've dug into protocols and delegates, which I've already used in a few places in my app and am admittedly still confused about, but then came across what seems like a more simple solution, which I can't get to work.

This solution is updating a variable in my instantiated view controller at the moment of instantiation.

I'm using Mapbox and on tap of an annotation, I'm looking to pass a unique value stored in my database to a detail view about the annotation. I've simplified my example below to all that I think matters to solve the problem.

In my first view controller, the map view:

```
// function that fires on annotation tap
func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, didSelect annotation: MGLAnnotation) {

        let placeID = "123456" // simplified for the purpose of this question

        func createPlaceDetailSheet() {

            let placeDetailSheet = PlaceDetailViewController()

            self.addChildViewController(placeDetailSheet)
            self.view.addSubview(placeDetailSheet.view)
            placeDetailSheet.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

            let height = view.frame.height
            let width  = view.frame.width
            placeDetailSheet.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.maxY, width: width, height: height)

            placeDetailSheet.uniqueID = "123456" // trying to set value here
    }

        createPlaceDetailSheet()
    }
```

In the second view controller, I have the following:

```
class PlaceDetailViewController: UIViewController {

    var uniqueID: String = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(uniqueID)
    }
}
```

I expect the unique ID ("123456") to be printed from the second view controller, but only the empty string initializer is being printed.

I've read through hours and hours of Stack Overflow articles trying to solve this and am at my absolute wit's end. Most answers rely upon the usage of performSegue, which I'm not using. I'm also not sure whether the approach above, or using protocols and delegates is the right call.

Thank you.

Comment: get `createPlaceDetailSheet` out of `didSelect`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The view is loaded when you access the variable to add the subview, therefore your print statement in the `viewDidLoad` method is executed before you set the `uniqueID` value of the controller.

Set the `uniqueID` right after your instatiate the controller class.

```
let placeDetailSheet = PlaceDetailViewController()

placeDetailSheet.uniqueID = "123456"
```

---

Alternatively, create a custom controller initializer that takes a unique ID as an argument.

```
class PlaceDetailViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: Properties

    var uniqueID: String = ""

    // MARK: Initializers

    init(uniqueID: String) {
        self.uniqueID = uniqueID
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    // MARK: View Lifecycle

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(uniqueID)
    }
}

let placeDetailSheet = PlaceDetailViewController(uniqueID: "foo")
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I used you first solution to solve my problem.

I'm curious though, would you recommend one approach over the other in my context in terms of best practice? I feel the custom init would be beneficial as my secondary controller scales to require more functionality.

Thanks again.